# Lazy load and route to component in module

Tags: angular

I have the following routes on my `home.routing.module.ts`:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AnonymousGuard] },
  { path: 'press', component: PressComponent, canActivate: [AnonymousGuard] },
  { path: 'legal', component: LegalComponent, canActivate: [AnonymousGuard] },
  { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent, canActivate: [AnonymousGuard] },
  { path: 'invite/:id', component: InviteComponent, canActivate: [AnonymousGuard] },
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: '../auth/auth.module#AuthModule' },
  // this doesn't work, it takes me to "login"
  { path: 'register', loadChildren: '../auth/auth.module#AuthModule' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

I have the following routes on my `auth.routing.module.ts`:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [AnonymousGuard] },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [AnonymousGuard] },
  { path: 'forgot-password', component: ForgotPasswordComponent, canActivate: [AnonymousGuard] },
  // this works if if I type in "/login/register"
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent, canActivate: [AnonymousGuard] },
  { path: 'verify-email', component: VerifyEmailComponent, canActivate: [AnonymousGuard] },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

I want to make `register` accessible at `register` instead of `login/register` from home-routing-module, how can I do this?

Comment: Structure ur app to a Register Module where u route at the ' ' path to the RegisterComponent. Same for Login. Now u can define a route At home Module 'register' and bind your module. Regards

Comment: Can I do it without a register module?

Comment: Looking at ur appstructure I dont see a way. BTW for ur bundlesize this is not a bad idea as it is going to lazyload and reduce ur bundlesize